# how to embed a screenshot in html report for every scene that passes in rspec

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec2, capybara-webkit, rspec3

When I do the automated tests the capybara generates an html with the report of the tests that passed or nao.com the cucumber of the to embed the photos of the tests in the html report

how to embed a screenshot in html for every scene that passes in rspec??

has a method in the cucumber that embed the screenshot in html
embed(screenshot, 'image/png', 'Click here')

but in rspec i not found.

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to clarify exactly what you're trying to do here since the embedding into an HTML embed doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: When I do the automated tests the capybara generates an html with the report of the tests that passed or nao.com the cucumber of the to embed the photos of the tests in the html report

Answer (score 0):

In your `spec_helper` you can do:

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each) do
    page.save_screenshot('image_%s.png' % rand(1000).to_s)
  end
end
```

If your formatter is outputting html it should just embed it into the html after each passing scenario.